# Filling the data gaps with a gray area using Highcharts,

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've a Highcharts Line Chart. Sometimes, there's a gap between the data and I wonder whether it's possible to fill these gaps with some gray area so it's better visible that there are no data.

Thanks

Edit: Example of what I want to have:
[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot regarding the 'gaps'?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-missing/ This is a jsfidlle with some gaps. I want these gaps to be highlighted with a gray rect.

Comment: so do you want the complete column to be grey or upto a certain height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`xAxis.plotBands`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands) to fill those gaps. Note you need to calculate where you have `null`-points in a first place, before rendering a chart.

Here is a simple example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/hbzoLxnw/

Answer (score 1):

you can set up a function to fill the gap:

```
  $('#button').click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < chart.yAxis[0].series[1].yData.length; i++) {
      if (chart.yAxis[0].series[1].yData[i] == null) {
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
          from: i - 1,
          to: i + 1,
          color: '#FCFFC5',
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Basically, the function above detect the `null` value, and sets up a `plotBands`.
The idea is here, but you can make it more versatile by checking if the value is at the beginning or the end, in this case, you don't have to write `i+1` or `i-1` but just `i`
Check the example ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/ownqned0/)):

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'area',
      spacingBottom: 30
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit consumption *'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: '* Jane\'s banana consumption is unknown',
      floating: true,
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      y: 15
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      x: 150,
      y: 100,
      floating: true,
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Grapes', 'Plums', 'Strawberries', 'Raspberries']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Y-Axis'
      },
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value;
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5
      },
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'John',
      data: [0, 1, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7]
    }, {
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [1, 0, 3, null, 3, 1, 2, 1]
    }]
  });


  // the button action
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

  $('#button').click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < chart.yAxis[0].series[1].yData.length; i++) {
      if (chart.yAxis[0].series[1].yData[i] == null) {
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
          from: i - 1,
          to: i + 1,
          color: '#FCFFC5',
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```